# Querying Master Record in test class vs. in DevConsole

Tags: unit-test, class

We have a Test class the query a Master record deatils and get nulls only in the test class, in "real" run (via annanumence code run)  - it does get values.

Any idea?

Code:

```
Success__c suc = (Success__c)SmartFactory.createSObject('Success__c');
suc.Account__c=acc.Id;
suc.Opportunity__c=opp.Id;
User successOwner=[select Id,LastName,IsActive from User where UserRole.Name like '%CSM%' and IsActive=true limit 1];
system.debug('Tal Carmi emvcsmic successOwner: '+successOwner);
suc.OwnerId=successOwner.Id;
insert suc;

suc=[select Id,OwnerId,Owner.LastName,Owner.IsActive from Success__c where Id=:suc.Id];
system.assertEquals(successOwner.Id,suc.OwnerId);

system.debug('Tal Carmi emvcsmic suc: '+suc);
system.debug('Tal Carmi emvcsmic suc.OwnerId: '+suc.OwnerId);
system.debug('Tal Carmi emvcsmic suc.Owner.LastName: '+suc.Owner.LastName);
system.debug('Tal Carmi emvcsmic suc.Owner.IsActive: '+suc.Owner.IsActive);
```

Log:
[image]

Comment: You've only shown part of your code. Are you creating the Master Record, using SeeAllData=true, or importing a set of test data? You'll need to do one of those in order to solve your issue or else mock the Master Record.